# Getting access to an attribute of another class

Tags: java, class, methods

I have two classes:

Inside class A, I have a method, which needs an attribute (trainingDuration) of class B:

```
Class A {
     public int caloryConsumption (int minutes) {
       return ((caloriesBurnedPerHour / 60) * trainingDuration);
     }
}
```

In class B, the attribute is set as a private String and I created a constructor, a setter and a getter but how am I able to get access to this attribute inside class A? I tried nearly everything, but it is shown as an error all the time...
Shouldn't it just be "B.getTrainingDuration"?

Comment: How trainingDuration is declared,  is it static?. If it is not static you need instance of class B to access

Comment: Show more code, including the main().  Also, why is trainingDuration a String?  Used in a calculation, it should be some type of number.

Comment: Oh sorry, i wrote it too quick :D Of course it is declared as an int. It is declared as an private int.

Comment: If you want to use `trainingDuration` in class B's method `caloryConsumption()` define your method as public int caloryConsumption(int minutes, int trainingDuration) and also i can see `minutes` parameter is unused. You need to refactor your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to change the method caloryConsumption and add a parameter of class Trainingsession.
so whenever you want to invoke the method caloryConsumption you pass the number of minutes + a reference to an object of the class Trainingsession so you can invoke its method.

your method is going to be like this:

```
public int caloryConsumption (int minutes, Trainingsession ts ) {
return ((caloriesBurnedPerHour / 60) * ts.gettrainingDuration());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Trainingsession { <- my mentioned class B

private int trainingDuration;
private int date;
private int startingtime;
private FitnessEquipment fitnessequipment;

public Trainingsession(int date, int startingtime FitnessEquipment fitnessequipment, int trainingDuration){
    this.date = date;
    this.startingtime = startingtime;
    this.fitnessequipment = fitnessequipment;
    this.trainingDuration = trainingDuration;
```

After that, there are the setters and getters, but I think, that I dont need to show them.

My other class has the methode, mentioned above and for that, I need trainingDuration from the other class, but I dont know how I am able to get this attribute.

Comment: This should be an edit to your question, not an answer. And yes you should show your getters and setters as that's what you're asking about.